# Setting focus for MVC (Html.TextBoxFor) using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an MVC project and am trying to set the focus on this:

```
<td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(de => Model.EmailAddress1)%></td>
```

My jquery is in the same view near the top of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id$=MainContent_EmailAddress1").focus();
        $("#EmailAddress1").focus();
    });
</script>
```

I've tried a few combinations to set the focus to this box but nothing I've tried works.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: It's not depending of your ASP MVC, it's purely depending of the rendered DOM structure !
Get it with "View source code" or a console, then you will know what to bind !

Answer (score 1):

You could take several steps in solving your problem. First of all, load your html and see, weather the id being rendered matches with the one that you provided. Secondly, I'd rather suggest you more rigid way to capture the element, or control the output.

You could add an extra functional class to grab the element

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailAddress1, new { @class = "fHandleClass" });
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  $(function(){
      $(".fHandleClass").focus();
  });
//]]>
</script>
```

Or you could directly control the id

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailAddress1, new { id = "MyExactId" });
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  $(function(){
      $("#MyExactId").focus();
  });
//]]>
</script>
```

And finally, I suggest you to switch to razor view engine. It is much better, the Web forms view engine were designed to be understood by the designers, it is not very friendly for handwriting. 
Razor was specifically designed for being written by hand.

Comment: Thanks, maybe we should get Razor.  Unfortunately, none of your suggestions worked.  I was hoping changing the id would work at least.